# How to execute Activity if Lookup return nothing in Azure Data Factory?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have Lookup making query SELECT CustomerName FROM Customers.
There is chance that request return no rows.

I would like to execute different activity based on if Lookup returned anything or not.

If 0 rows THEN do nothing or move to Activity A
If rows exist THEN move to Activity B

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an If Condition activity to check the outcome of the Lookup.

[image: Output of Lookup activity]